# Why does the Capacity property not update in my textbox?

Tags: c#, string

Length property populates respective textBox3 fine and updates value correctly as strings are appended from textBox1. textBox4 only reads 16, the initial StringBuilder value (default), it does not change to 32 at the 17th character (nor 64 at the 33rd character).

Why doesn't Capacity property continue to populate/update textBox4?

```
public partial class StringBuilderExercise : Form
{
    public StringBuilderExercise()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    // input textbox
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    // button appends textBox1 string to textBox2
    private void append_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
        textBox3.Text = textBox2.Text.Length.ToString();
        textBox4.Text = buffer.Capacity.ToString();
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
    //read-only textbox to display string append concat
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    //read-only textbox to display length of string
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
    }
    //read-only textbox to display capacity of string buffer
    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
    }
}
```

Comment: You never actually add anything to `buffer`, why would it increase its capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you never Append any data to the StringBuilder.

I imagine you mean to something like this:

```
buffer.Append(textBox1.Text);
```